# Facebook logout after background

Tags: ios, facebook, logout

I have application that use Facebook SDK for login. Have a problem with auto logout, when application goes to background and stays at background for a while, application logouts. And i need to login again(but without entering login/email, just press ok) and that it takes me back to application.
Can anyone help with that?

Comment: application logouts ? does it mean facebook logout or something else .. maybe your custom webservice ?

Comment: Customer sent me this video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oI9LmhEXYkMlZ1cDRjcjc4NDQ/view

Application on viewWillApear checks Facebook access token and if it has valid token it goes through application login process, in other ways it stays here. But it seems that this problem not in access token, because customer says that it can logout after he logins and goes to background, whats few minutes -> needs to login again

Comment: this requires more debugging and isn't fit for this site till you got a specific problem which you need help with. You should find out at least the cause of logout yourself